# Como referenciar o software original numa modificação?

Tags: licença

Eu estou criando um package para o Laravel com base num código que utiliza a licença BSD (https://github.com/reactjs/react-php-v8js/blob/master/ReactJS.php).

Como exatamente devo referenciá-lo? Devo manter o arquivo de licença sem alterações? Ou talvez manter o original e adicionar a minha licença...?
Como isso costuma ser feito?

Answer (score 1):

Veja o que [a licença original](https://github.com/reactjs/react-php-v8js/blob/master/LICENSE) diz sobre isso:

> Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without modification,
>   are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
>
> - Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice, this
>     list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
> - Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice,
>     this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation
>     and/or other materials provided with the distribution.

Ou seja, você pode redistribuir, mas **deve** manter o copyright acima e o disclaimer abaixo desses parágrafos, independente de todo o resto.

O padrão que vejo em alguns projetos é manter as licenças de todos os componentes que utilizam, e adicionar a própria. Acho que seria o ideal ter sua própria licença, em adição ao arquivo de licença desse projeto que você vai utilizar.

Dei uma olhada no MojoPortal, que é um desses tipos de projeto. Cada componente que ele usa, mesmo se binário (ou seja, não a fonte, mas o componente compilado), fica em uma pasta própria. E dentro dessa pasta o Mojo tem um arquivo .txt com a licença do componente. Esses arquivos ficam inalterados. Dá uma olhada na [página geral de licenças deles](https://www.mojoportal.com/license.aspx) pra ter uma ideia de como fazer: eles listam cada programa que tem uma licença diferente do Mojo. Acho que vale a pena se inspirar na redação que tem lá.

Comment: Então, mas como exatamente isso fica organizado? Meu package não possui o código fonte do package original, mas a ideia é a mesma e utilizo uma estrutura semelhante. A licença tem "Copyright (c) 2014, Facebook, Inc. All rights reserved.". Eu devo manter isso aí? O arquivo LICENSE deve permanecer o mesmo? Senão, onde devo incluir este arquivo? A minha dúvida está mais em onde colocar cada coisa (falando em termos de arquivos mesmo). Obrigado.

Comment: O segundo item da lista fala sobre redistribuição em forma binária ;) Quanto ao resto, vou editar a resposta.

Comment: Vamos ver se entendi. Eu criei uma pasta `licenses` (como no Mojo) e coloquei um `license-react-php-v8js.txt` lá com uma cópia da licença do projeto do fb. Daí, para ficar claro, vou colocar no meu README que o projeto foi baseado nele e colocar o link do repositório. Já resolve?

Comment: Acho que sim. Apenas confirme com mais alguém, pois eu mesmo não sou especialista nisso.